# Windows within OSX VMWare Fusion not able to access mac partitions

Tags: windows-7, macos, partitioning, boot-camp, vmware-fusion

when I run my bootcamp Windows 7 natively, I installed macdrive and it can see all of the HFS+ partitions as windows drive letters. Read/Write performance is great.

When I run my bootcamp Windows 7 partition in a virtual machine, My Computer does not show me the other partitions on the harddrive.

Its just a small caveat that I would like to fix. I saw that VMWare fusion would allow me to share OSX folders to the virtualized windows, but these will probably not show up in Windows as drive letters - and when I switch back to Windows natively (on a restart, for instance) then any programs that were looking for those shared folders would have a broken path - which is merely inconvenient.

How can I get the Windows 7 partition - both running either virtualized or running natively, to access all of my HDD partitions?

This HDD was formatted to have a general partition for storing personal content, that both OSs will be able to use - and not take space away from the system partitions.